# Control execution flow following the update of several reactive dependencies

Tags: r, shiny

This is a straightforward yet advanced problem. Here is a walkthrough:

I have three inputs i_1, i_2, i_3, that lead to three reactive values that are used in different functions:

```
I1 <- reactive({input$i_1})
I2 <- reactive({input$i_2})
I3 <- reactive({input$i_3})
```

Specifically, these three values are used to plot a graph as a reactive endpoint:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot {(
    plot( f(I1(), I2(), I3()) )
)}
```

The shiny magic works out and everything works fine, until I want to load some data and modify the three i_X values:

```
observe {(
  input$b_Load #Load button
  [...]
  updateSelectInput(session,"i_1", value = 4)
  updateSelectInput(session,"i_2", value = 3)
  updateSelectInput(session,"i_3", value = 5)
  ...
)}
```

The update itself works fine, and the three new values for the variables are sent to the client.

**The problem:** The values are then updated and sent back one by one to the server, which recomputes the graph each time unnecessarily. I would like to update the graph only once, when all the values are updated. Is it possible?

---

**I tried** to wait for an onFlushed event:

```
  values <- reactiveValues(loadingProfile = FALSE)

  session$onFlushed(function() {
    values$loadingProfile <- FALSE
    cat("##### DEBUG: loading Profile OFF ##############\n", file = stderr())
  }, once = FALSE)

  output$plot <- renderPlot {(
    if (!values$loadingProfile) {
      plot( f(I1(), I2(), I3()) )
    }
  )}

  observe {(
    input$b_Load #Load button
    values$loadingProfile <- TRUE #Toggle on the watching value
    cat("##### DEBUG: loading Profile ON ##############\n", file = stderr())
    [...]
    updateSelectInput(session,"i_1", value = 4)
    updateSelectInput(session,"i_2", value = 3)
    updateSelectInput(session,"i_3", value = 5)
    ...
  )}
```

but it doesn't work because the session is flushed each time one of the three updated versions is sent back to the server... (I checked on the console after activating the trace)

---

What will not work properly:

- **Counting events**, as suggested by @jdharrison, can be a good hack but will not work here because if the loaded value with `updateSelectInput()` is the same as it used to be, the value is not sent back.
- **Waiting a bit**, with something like `invalidateLater(2000, session)` kinda works (I tried it) but is not robust. It is not possible to specify a time that will always catch the different exchanges without overshooting and thus pausing execution for too long.

Comment: Hi Antoine, I am I trying to do something very similar to your problem right now. Did you end up finding a solution, or what approach did you end up using? Thank you.

Comment: @johnny838 I ended up refactoring based on reactive() values. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question doesn't have an answer per se from what I know of the current state of Shiny. Nevertheless, using the awesome `reactive()` expressions, I've been able to refactor the flow of values and update the graph only once. In deed the

```
output$plot <- renderPlot {(
  plot( f(User()) )
)}

observe {(
  input$b_Load #Load button
  updateSelectInput(session,"i_1", value = 4)
  updateSelectInput(session,"i_2", value = 3)
  updateSelectInput(session,"i_3", value = 5)
  ...
)}

User <- reactive({
  object <- list()
  object$i1 <- I1()
  object$i2 <- I2()
  object$i3 <- I3()
)}
```

+ a small rewrite of `f()`.

Here, the `User()` reactive expression plays the role of the buffer. It will wait for all the previous changes to be pushed before sending its own value to `f()`.

I have shared my full Shiny project on [Github](https://github.com/antoine-lizee/BIHack), for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following would most likely solve your problem. I haven't tested it but

Set

```
values <- reactiveValues(loadingProfile = 0)
```

In `renderPlot` :

```
output$plot <- renderPlot {(
  if (values$loadingProfile %/% 4 == 0) {
    plot( f(I1(), I2(), I3()) )
  }else{
    values$loadingProfile <- values$loadingProfile + 1
  }
)}
```

remove the call to `session$onFlushed` and change the assignment in the `observe`to:

```
isolate(values$loadingProfile <- values$loadingProfile + 1)
```

As an example:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      selectInput("id1", "select a number", 1:5)
      , selectInput("id2", "select a small letter", letters[1:5])
      , selectInput("id3", "select a BIG letter", LETTERS[1:5])
      , textOutput("text")
      , actionButton("myBtn", "Press me!!!")
    )
    , server = function(input, output, session){
      values <- reactiveValues(loadingProfile = 0)
      I1 <- reactive({input$id1})
      I2 <- reactive({input$id2})
      I3 <- reactive({input$id3})
      output$text <- renderText({
        if (values$loadingProfile %/% 4 == 0) {
          paste(I1(), I2(), I3())
        }else{
          values$loadingProfile <- values$loadingProfile + 1
        }
      })
      observe({
        if(input$myBtn > 0){
          isolate(values$loadingProfile <- values$loadingProfile + 1)
          updateSelectInput(session,"id1", "select a number", 1:5, selected = 5)
          updateSelectInput(session,"id2", "select a small letter", letters[1:5], selected = "e")
          updateSelectInput(session,"id3", "select a BIG letter", LETTERS[1:5], selected = "E")
        }
      })
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had something similar in mind, but I don't like counting events in general. Here, it will not work, because if one of the values that are updated doesn't change, it will not be sent back. Hence, the counter might have to be ```%/% 3```, ```2```, or  ```1``` depending on the case...